# What should I use to backup my home partition to optical media?

Tags: backup

I have been looking around for a backup utility to handle breaking up my home folder backup across a set of blu-ray discs. Aside from using brasero to manually add each file and folder I want include, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it but [Dkopp claims to be able to do this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/dkopp/):

> Dkopp is a program used to copy or back-up disk files to DVD or BD (Blue-ray) media. Full or incremental backups can be done, with full or incremental media verification. A GUI is used to navigate through directories to select or de-select files or directories at any level. Backup jobs can be saved for later re-use. New, deleted, and updated disk files are handled automatically, without re-editing the backup job. An incremental backup updates the same DVD/BD media used for a prior full backup. Files can be restored to the same or another location on disk. **Large backup jobs can be done using multiple DVD media.**

Comment: So close, but there are a few problems. While it does exactly what I want, I had to get the updated version from its [homepage](http://www.kornelix.com/dkopp.html) to make it stop crashing. Currently it freaks out at the file count being over 200,000 (It's actually 189,439 without excluding things.) and refuses to acknowledge my BD-R drive when it has a disc inside it.